Typescript conditional types, with conditional value
function Test<Multiple extends boolean>(multiple: Multiple) {
  const value: Multiple extends true ? string[] : string = (multiple ? [] : "");
}

Why do I get the below error for this?
Error: Argument of type "" | never[] is not assignable to parameter of type
I expect it to be correct syntax.

(see prev comment, and pls [edit]) TS5.7 has no facility to deal with generic conditional types this way; there's no control flow analysis on generic type params. TS5.8 will introduce ms/TS#56941 which lets you return generic conditional types for particular scenarios; you can write a helper fn and use it inside Test, as shown in this playground link. Note how the conditional type has to end in : never and not : string as per the PR. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

given the recent edit, this playground link is the new version of how I'd address it in TS5.8 and above. Please read prev comment and let me know how you want to proceed.
